# How to change the alignment of list bullets

Tags: html, css

I have used an image in place of bullets in my unordered list and I want to make it centered according to the text. My bullet is not in the center. How can I change its position?

[image]

```
.ul {
    list-style-image: url(../images/arrow.svg);
  }//This is code for replacing default bullets with with image
```

Comment: Could you say exactly where you want it in relation to the text. And put a runnable snippet, including the svg, into your question.

Answer (score 0):

try ::before example:

```
ul {
  position: relative;
}
ul::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; /* transform image to center */
  transform: translateY(-50%); /*transform image to center */
  left: 20px; /* custom change*/
  background-image: url('../images/arrow.svg');
  background-size: 10px 20px; /* custom size Here  must be same as width and height*/
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;  /* custom size Here */
  height: 20px; /* custom size Here */
  content:"";
 }
```